# npx create-react-app myapp command throwning error

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to create an app in react . I have installed the latest Node js
when I am running the command I am getting error

[image: The following error is coming.]

PS C:\Users\Kumar Sanket\Desktop\React&Redux> npx create-react-app myapp
Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\Kumar'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
    at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:228:22)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:266:24
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7
    at Array.forEach ()
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13
    at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:173:20)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:47:53
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205
  if (npm.config.get('json')) {
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
    at process.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27)
Install for create-react-app@latest failed with c

Comment: getting the same error

Comment: there is issue on github so, dont really know what to tell you, but try to install older version of `CRA` https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6512

Comment: Try using `npm init react-app my-app`

Answer (score 14):

Today I encountered a similar issue with *npx create-react-app my-app*(mkdir failed).

**Reason for my error**

1. I had space in my user name folder(ex: Abc Xyz) and thus *"npx"* couldn't refer to it correctly (It only read Abc, and not Xyz).
2. I am using VS Code for React, and it didn't had the permission to create new directory

**How I fixed it**

1. Opened VS Code with Administrator rights.(fixed permission issue)
2. Instead of using *"npx"* I tried the following:

   --> *npm install -g create-react-app*

   --> *create-react-app my-app*

**And that got executed successfully.**

**Hope this helps.**

Answer (score 9):

The problem is the space in the username. I use Windows 10 and I solved it by changing the path of npm cache folder in this way:

1. run `npm config get cache` to check the value of property cache in your config file
2. if path contains a white space, you can replace the string after the space with '~1', e.g. I have `C:\Users\Andrea R\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`
3. therefore run `npm config set cache 'C:\Users\Andrea~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache'`

Comment: Thanks Andrea, that's what I needed. FWIW, I had to remove the single quotes around the path I was trying to set: npm config set cache C:\Users\Andrea~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

Comment: This worked for me. I just had to run VSCode again with administrator rights after this, because I got a permission error. 
But the original problem was fixed with this command. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

there is issue on github so, dont really know what to tell you, but try to install older version of CRA 
link: [github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6512](http://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6512)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it several times but was not successful . The main reason behind this was my username in the system was "Kumar Sanket" and it was not able to read anything after space.
when I changed my username i was able to run the commands.
Thanks all for support
Kumar Sanket

Answer (score 0):

Install create-react-app using
npm install -g create-react-app

then use
create-react-app my-app

no npm or npx before create-react app.

Answer (score 0):

This EEXIST error happens due to path to node-cache directory contains a whitespace.
Steps worked for me:

1. create a directory manually named `node-cache` where path does not have any whitespace.
2. install node cache content using command `npm install --cache path/to/node-cache`
3. set the new node-cache dir using command `npm config set cache path/to/node-cache`
4. now run `npx create-react-app my-app`